# How can I customize this script to appear an image over another?

Tags: jquery, html, fadein

I have a script which cross fades the images. But I have some text images which I want to appear as fading in on every image. It means, when the first images comes, it will pause, then the text image will fade in on that images and then fades out. After that the second image fades in.

```
function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

// uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the text image fade-in within the callback to animate the next slide:

```
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500, function() {
        // Fade in/out text image here
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am newby at javascript. can you please elaborate more? thanks again.

Comment: The callback function is called right after the image appears, so it's a perfect spot to fade in and out the text image you mentioned. You can use the same way you're animating the other images or the more-specific `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods. Something like `$('#myTextImage').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');` would do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. The first image keeps fading out before the second one kicks in. and loop keeps going on between this two images only (first image and the text image).

    [ $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500, function() {
   $('#slideshow IMG:middle-active').fadeIn('slow').delay(1000).fadeOut('slow');
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });